# How do one select first in a lower.tri output?

Tags: r, matrix

I have an out from a lower.tri output and wnat to do the mean on the first column.

How to do that?

Comment: Isn't this just the first column of the original matrix without the first value? Something like `mean(m[-1,])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do it (and also get any column mean) would be to (instead of using `lower.tri` directly on the matrix) do the following:

```
#Assume a 5x5 matrix
a <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5)
#set upper.tri and the diag to NA
#so what you are left with is just the lower.tri values in a matrix
a[upper.tri(a)] <- diag(a) <- NA
```

Then it is easy to do:

```
colMeans(a, na.rm=TRUE)
[1]  3.5  9.0 14.5 20.0  NaN
```

And get all of them. `colMeans(a, na.rm=TRUE)[1]` will just give you the first.

Comment: Now how is this better than just `mean(a[-1,1])` like I suggested in comments while avoiding this whole process all together?

Comment: No one said it is better @DavidArenburg . This is just a generalized form I provided as an alternative (keeping in mind that someone might search for more than the 1st column in the future) and you didn't post as an answer :P.